# Accessing activity's state in CursorAdapter subclass

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I'm writing a fairly complex `ListView`, which (among other things) requires formatting Views in each list item.

To give me full control over how the views are bound in each list item, I subclassed `CursorAdapter` in this manner:

```
public class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final ToggleButton tButton = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.tbutton);
        tButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // start activity based on a pending intent
            }
        });     

    }
}
```

The issue is that my `ToggleButton` click listener should start an activity based on a pending intent. The pending intent is instantiated in the activity which utilises this customized adapter.

I'm aware I could have used a `SimpleCursorAdapter` in the main `Activity` with a `ViewBinder` so that launching the intent would only be necessary from the main `Activity`. But `SimpleCursorAdapter` is not quite right since I don't map columns straight to views.

However, the alternative I have here would suggest accessing the main `Activity`'s data from a cursor subclass. I feel that there must be a better way to design the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a cue from the API Demos - specifically `EfficientAdapter`, I have declared the `CursorAdapter` sublcass as an inner class of my activity.

This avoids passing the pending intent around outside of the main activity.

Source: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html